# creating an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

why the below javascript code is not working for me ? what changes should i make in the below code ?

```
function person(firstname, lastname, age, eyecolor)
{
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myFather[i] = new person("John", "Doe", i, "blue");
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    document.write(myFather[i].firstname + " is " +
                   myFather[i].age + " years old.");
}
```

Comment: How is it not working for you? Any error messages? Any unexpected results?

Comment: `ReferenceError: myFather is not defined`

Comment: Where do you initialise myFather as an array?

Comment: no output on the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see `myFather` being initialized anywhere. You need to do that before assigning array values into it.

```
var myFather = [];
```

Comment: `function person()` and `new person()` is working?

Comment: @MichelFeldheim: looks okay

Answer (score 1):

myFather variable is not initialized:

```
var myFather = new Array();
```